# Equation with binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, roots, roots-of-unity

Problem:
Find the roots of $6z^5+15z^4+20z^3+15z^2+6z+1 = 0$.

What I found: I realized that the coefficients were the binomial coefficients of $6$. Putting these values in, you would get $\dbinom{6}{1}z^5 + \dbinom{6}{2}z^4 + \dbinom{6}{3}z^3 + \dbinom{6}{4}z^2 + \dbinom{6}{5}z + \dbinom{6}{6} = 0$.

I also thought that maybe there was some applications of the roots of unity here, but I wasn't quite sure. Some help here would be really awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Vieta's formulae?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint : Rewrite your equation as $(z+1)^6-z^6=0$ and since $z=0$ isn't a solution, show that $\frac{z+1}{z}$ is a 6-th root of unity.

Comment: So we have $(z+1)^6=z^6$, but how would you prove it is a root of unity w/o having the $1$ in the equation?

Comment: Wait, nevermind. $(z+1)^6=z^6$ becomes $\frac{(z+1)^6}{z^6}=(\frac{z+1}{z})^6=1$. Thanks for the really really good hint!